# How do I display reCAPTCHA in modals with different id?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal, recaptcha

This is my code:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<?php
    $result = $DBConnect->query("SELECT id FROM table");
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) { ?>

        <a href="#" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> Reply</a>
    <?php  include "modal.php"; } ?>

// modal.php


      <div class="modal fade" id="modal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label>Name : </label>
                                <input type="text" name="customer_name" class="pass-input" value="" required>
                                <label>Email : </label>
                                <input type="email" name="customer_email" class="pass-input" value="">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div id="captcha"></div>
                            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
                        </div>
               </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(function () {
       var anchor = window.location.hash;
       $(anchor).modal('show');
       setTimeout(function() {
        createRecaptcha();
        }, 100);
    });
    function createRecaptcha() {
        grecaptcha.render("captcha", {sitekey: "SITE_KEY", theme: "light"});
    }
 </script>
```

In above code `Recaptcha` works for modal opened when I click first `Reply` button in list of many `Reply` buttons. When I click other `Reply` buttons `Recaptcha` wont display in the modal popup since I used only used only one id in `<div id="captcha"></div>`.

How can I modify my code so that when I open different modal, `Recaptcha` will show in each modal.

Comment: You'll need to give each captcha div a unique ID like you do with the modals, and pass the relevant ID into createRecaptcha each time. You'll need to handle the event of the modal being shown (check the bootstrap docs) so that you can run the createRecaptcha function each time, whereas now you only run it when the page first loads.

Comment: @ADyson pass the relevant ID into createRecaptcha each time-- Can u please tell how to do this?

Comment: Like any value you pass into a function, e.g. `function createRecaptcha(id) {
        grecaptcha.render(id`...etc then you can call it like `var divID = "captcha1"; createRecaptcha(divID);`.

Comment: Or are you asking how to _decide_ which ID to pass in?

Comment: @ADyson How to fetch the modal id when I open modal each time?

Comment: Well if you handle the event of the modal being shown as I mentioned, that will give you access to the modal element, and its ID contains the ID you need - or you could put it into a data-attribute of the modal for convenience, and then prepend "captcha" to it, get it out and then pass it into the createRecaptcha function

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events explains about handling the modal event.